# Beer looses almost all carbonation when opened

Tags: carbonation, dry-hop

I followed [this recipe](https://thebeerhop.com/product/all-grain-kit-mr-malt-supertramp-brewing-apa/) for making an APA.

Since I have a smaller brewing kit (10~12 liters pan and fermentation bucket), I divided the ingredients for two batches:

- First one following every step and exactly the same hop additions. Also for the dry-hopping part.
- Second one I added some Columbus hops for the hop additions and dry-hopping as well. The other main difference was that I used also a Safale S-04 instead, since I was without US-05.

Both of them I did dry-hopping from the day zero of fermentation.

The first batch was okay, it lacked maybe a little bit more time for the dry-hop to be better, but the second batch, every bottle that I opened it produce a lot of foam and start to come out of the bottle loosing almost half of the beer and the remaining part is complete flat...

Can some clarify exactly what happend? I mean, I'm blaming the yeast since is not the one used for this kind of recipe, but maybe there's more to that.

Comment: I also had a batch of volcano bottles, which I also dry hopped, coincidence?  How did you prime your bottles (individually or batch)?  How well did you mixed the priming sugar?

Comment: hahaha, actually the name describes perfectly what happend. I did the priming for the batch, following the table for American Ales (2,2 ~2,7). I aimed to 2,4 and used [this calculator](https://www.brewersfriend.com/beer-priming-calculator/) to help the math. What I do normally is heat up some water (like 250ml) to approximately 24º C and mix the malt extract. For this one I used Pale Ale malt extract. After dissolved all the content, I stir the beer in the fermentation bucket gently and add slowly the sugar mix.

Comment: Although the fact that you have volcano bottles is a problem, try for this batch putting them in the freezer for like an hour before opening. When the beer is very cold, it is less "angry". It may not be enough to stop the volcano, but it will make it less angry.

Comment: But make sure you cool down all your bottles, or you may have to clean up a bunch of beer and glass when they explode.

Comment: @AviHirsch yeah! hahaha, I was considering opening another thread discussing how to handle volcano bottles. Until now, the best result that I've got was leaving the bottle in the freezer until it almost freezes and then open _reeeally_ slow, like 5 minutes to open it. I use the opener from a swiss army knife cause I found it easier to lift just a point in the cap and releasing the gas slowlly without _"upsetting/waking"_ the yeast in the bottom (I noticed that this seems to cause the violent eruptions). =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**What your describing is volcano bottles. Over carbonation**

This is caused by bottle conditioning with too much priming sugar, too much residual sugar or wild yeast infection.

Priming sugar misdose is easily prevented with proper measuring.

Residual sugar is prevented by taking final gravity readings to make sure fermentation is complete instead of a measure of time.

Wild yeast is prevented by good sanitation practices.

*I would guess that the second batch caught a wild yeast. This can be confirmed by possible off esters and very dry beer, as wilds can ferment sugars brewers yeast cannot.*

Comment: Over filled bottles or not mixing priming sugar enough could contribute to the problem as well.

Comment: @Philippe while it could add to the issue, it would still need one of the other three conditions to volcano.

Comment: Okay, now that you said it, I actually miscalculated the final volume, I was expecting 9 to 10L of beer at least as usual, but after bottling I ended up with almost 8L. Since I did the math for the priming with the 10L in mind, I'm sure that I over primed it... lesson learned: check the bucket volume before adding the sugar, hahaha
I'm discarding the wild yeast and residual sugar options because I got no off taste from it (I use peracetic acid and alcohol 70º for sanitation always) and it was the second day without dropping the density as verified. =)
Also, sorry S-04 for blaming you. hahaha

Comment: @leomilrib glad you able to identify the cause! Happy brewing!